# JQuery:Selector unexpected selector change

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dynamic

Hello I have a quite strange problem I'm coding a Rails App and I am trying to do sth like this:

```
if ($('.btnModal').exists()) {
  $('.btnModal').bind('click', function() {
    var $modal, fadeTime, modalCustomClass;

    $modal = $('#myModal');
    fadeTime = 1000;
    modalCustomClass = $(this).data('modal_content_selector').substring(1);
    $modal.removeClass(modalCustomClass).addClass(modalCustomClass);

    alert(modalCustomClass);
    alert($($(this).data('modal_content_selector')).html());
    alert($(this).data('modal_content_selector'));

    return $('.modal-body').html($($(this).data('modal_content_selector')).html());
  });
}
```

This line `$modal.removeClass(modalCustomClass).addClass(modalCustomClass)` results in this situation:

The second alert displays the html of selctor .modal-body but without this line the situation is correct, the mentioned selector displays the html of a form which is in the page. I've read sth about live and delagate methods but I don't know how to use them here

EDIT:
There it is:
This is show for catalog:

```
- provide(:title, "#{ current_catalog.name }")
= render 'shared/desktop'
= render 'shared/file_upload'
```

This is modal partial:

```
      .modal.hide#myModal{ overflow: 'hidden', tabindex: '-1', role: 'dialog', 'aria-        hidden' => 'true' }
        .modal-body
           TEST
```

And part of the sidebar with the specific button:

```
          %li
            %a.btn.btnModal{ href: "#myModal", role: 'button', data: { toggle: 'modal',   'modal_content_selector' => '.file_upload' }, remote: 'true'}
              %i.icon-file
              New
```

Another Edit:

Here is the html of the whole rendered page:

[Whole page](http://pastebin.com/irqwNAkg)

Comment: Could you clarify what the expected behaviour of your code is, and by contrast, what you're experiencing instead? Additionally, may I recommend defining an additional variable in your click-handler, `modalContentSelector`, and extract the expression `$(this).data('modal_content_selector')` to it? It will make your code a lot more readable, I suspect.

Comment: Another thing: in your modal partial, one of the Haml attributes you've specified is actually a style rule: `overflow: 'hidden'`. This should instead be: `.modal.hide#myModal{ style: 'overflow: hidden', tabindex: '-1'...`.

Comment: Daniel you are right I will remember it and make it more clear code. However the effect I wanted to achieve is add to modal different classes depend on the place and purpose it is being used. I wanted to do it in dynamic and generic way. The whole idea seems maybe a bit tricky but it can work, but sth is wrong with the selector in second alert if I use the remove and add class operation above it

Comment: I think you're better off having a different `div.modal` for each type of modal your page will need, rather than using jQuery to manipulate the HTML in one modal. You'll end up with more HTML markup, but a considerably less-complicated Javascript implementation.

Comment: You are only partialy right becouse everything works fine apart from this dynamic class adding. I wanted to make it some kind of a feature and it would rather make my html more simple but adding a class was ment to custumize the modal depend on the content it will have. Instead of that I see that I will have to choose one shared custoziation for all my modal situations

Answer (score 0):

I just got enlighted and realized that adter I do this removeClass.addClass stuff I have on a page TWO elements which have the same class that is why the second alert displayed the first on the one I need is at the last position on the page so sth like this: alert($($(this).data('modal_content_selector') + ':last').html()); should do the trick :D